# Extract data call and change in R using getCall()

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to extract the `data` argument from a function call, manipulate that data, then re-evaluate the function call.

Minimal working example:

```
fit <- lm(disp ~ hp,
          data = mtcars)

getCall(fit)$data
```

> mtcars

Now imagine I want to change the `hp` variable by adding random noise to each value. In other words, the `data` argument now needs to be:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    mutate(hp = hp + rnorm(n()))
```

How can I get the first call to `data` using `getCall` and update it with just the new data modifications?

Something like the following would be desired:

```
fit2 <- update(fit,
               data = getCall(fit)$data %>%
                   mutate(hp = hp + rnorm(n())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getCall(fit)$data` returns an object of type "name", you can simply use `eval` to get the actual dataset out of it and use it within `update`:

```
fit2 <- update(fit, 
               data = eval(getCall(fit)$data) %>% 
                        mutate(hp = hp + rnorm(n())))

fit2

# Call:
# lm(formula = disp ~ hp, data = eval(getCall(fit)$data) %>% mutate(hp = hp + rnorm(n())))

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           hp  
#      21.676        1.423
```